# Couchbase compression free disk space requirement

Tags: couchbase

According to [old documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/3.x/admin/Tasks/tasks-compaction-process.html):

> If the amount of available disk space is less than twice the current database size, the compaction process does not take place and a warning is issued in the log.

Assuming this is still relevant for Couchbase 5.x (I couldn't find it in the latest docs), I'd like to know whether this requirement is truly for the entire bucket size (or even the entire database) - or rather per vBucket that's being compacted at a given point in time (since the compaction process happens per vBucket, with only 3 working in parallel by default).

If it's per compacting vBucket, I'd be less worried about having my single bucket take more than 50% of disk size, which right now I'm wary of and so I keep a very large margin of disk unutilized.

Comment: I submitted an issue to the docs team. You may want to follow-up and/or keep an eye on the issue: https://github.com/couchbase/docs-cb4/issues/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This questions was also asked on the Couchbase [forums](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-compression-free-disk-space-requirement/16686). I have copied my answer from there:

> Assuming this is still relevant for Couchbase 5.x

This is still correct for Couchbase Server 5.X.

The recommendation is on the size of the whole bucket as you noted.

The calculation itself to check if compaction has enough space to complete successfully is done per vBucket. In other words compaction will run as long as there is enough space for that one vBucket to be compacted.

> since the compaction process happens per vBucket, with only 3 working in parallel by default).

The default setting has been changed to one - for more details see [MB-18426](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-18426)

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find documentation in 5.x either, but again, assuming that old documentation still holds true, I think it's probably at the vbucket level as you suspect (some notes from [Don Pinto in this old blog post](https://blog.couchbase.com/compaction-magic-couchbase-server-20/) seem to confirm). However, while documents are distributed relatively evenly between vbuckets, the actual size can vary, so I wouldn't make any assumptions about vbucket size if you're looking at disk space. Indexes also take up disk space.

But also note that if you're concerned about running into disk size limits, you can add another node, which will redistribute the vbuckets, and should free up more space on every node.